# Angular Masonry options not working

Tags: angularjs, user-interface, masonry, angular-masonry

I'm unable to set options for ng-Masonry: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-masonry

```
<div class="masonry" data-masonry data-masonry-options='{ "columnWidth": 1000, "gutter": 10 }'>
```

None of the options I set appear in the UI. Any way around this?

Comment: which version of angular are you using?

Comment: I'm using angular 1.4.9

Comment: Share your code over plunkr . No one can comment whats wrong unless you share what you have written

Comment: I'm using company code, so it's hard to duplicate the exact settings I'm using.

Comment: I've noticed when I type "new Masonry('.masonry', {gutter: 20});" in the browser, the options work. However, on initial load, the options fail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer: I was using an old version of ngMasonry, which had a typo: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-masonry. By linking to the latest version it worked.